# Can circularly polarized light resonate in a Fabry-Perot cavity?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I am curious as to how a standing wave of circularly polarized light may be forced to resonate in a Fabry Perot cavity as in this paper - https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.035021

I know that in a standard Fabry Perot cavity with incident linearly polarized light, the standing wave produced has the magnetic and electric field components 90 degrees out of phase (and of course perpendicular).

Is it also true that a circularly polarized beam resonant in a Fabry Perot cavity capped with quarter wave plates has a structure where the magnetic field component is 90 degrees out of phase with the electric field component?

[image: From https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.035021]

Answer (score 1):

Circularly polarised light is two linearly polarised electromagnetic waves with their electric fields at right angles to one another and $\pi/2$ out of phase.
So if it works out for each component of the electric/magnetic field what does superposition imply?

Comment: I was going to post a sort-of equivalent answer, to wit: if the phase shift at the reflecting surface for the two linear components is either the same or $k*\pi$ off, everything works.